# Not able to scrape the element which gets added on dropdown change using python & beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There is a page which has data and the dropdown on it. There are some elements like product code which only gets added when the dropdown option is selected and changes with the different selected option.

I am able to **scrape** the page, able to click the dropdown and show the product code on the page with python & selenium script but it still not able to **scrape** product code

```
import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ramanmac/Projects/PycharmProjects/ScrappingProject/chromedriver')
npo_jobs = {}  # Empty dictionary to store all the records
job_no = 0

website = 'website that I want to scrape'
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
menus = soup.find("ul", {"class": "ubermenu-submenu-id-7074"}).findAll("li", {"class": "ubermenu-item-level-2"})
for menu in menus:
    item = menu.find("a", {"class": "ubermenu-item-layout-text_only"})
    categoryPage = item.get('href')
    if categoryPage == "#":continue
    weblink=""
    if (categoryPage.find("http") == -1):
        weblink = website + categoryPage
    else:
        weblink = categoryPage
    categoryPageName = item.find('span', {"class": "ubermenu-target-title"}).text
    print("Inside FOR Name => " + categoryPageName)
    driver.get(weblink)
    htmlPage = driver.page_source
    soupPage = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage, "html.parser")
    containers = soupPage.find("ul", {"class": "products"}).findAll("li", {"class": "product"})
    print(len(containers))
    for container in containers:
        innerlink = container.find("a", {"class": "woocommerce-LoopProduct-link"}).get('href')
        # print(innerlink)
        driver.get(innerlink)
        htmlPage = driver.page_source
        soupPage = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage, "html.parser")
        container = soupPage.findAll("div", {"id": "product-row"})
        dpflag = 0
        try:
            select_fr = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="suma-select-variation"]/select'))
            dpflag = len(select_fr.options) - 1
        except:
            pass

        if dpflag == 0:
            # # we existing infra or rebuild web admin
            product_image = container[0].find("img", {"class": "wp-post-image"})['src']
            # #         print(product_image)
            product_name = container[0].find("h1", {"class": "entry-title"}).text
            #         # print(product_name)
            product_code = ""
            try:
                product_code = container[0].find("div", {"class": "suma-woo-product-sku"}).text
            except:
                pass  # doing nothing on exception
            print("Inside" + product_code)
            product_desc = ""  # container[0].find("div", {"class": "lead"}).text
            try:
                product_desc = container[0].find("div", {"class": "lead"}).text
            except:
                try:
                    product_desc = container[0].find("div", {"class": "lead"}).text
                except:
                    pass  # doing nothing on exception
            product_price = container[0].find("span", {"class": "woocommerce-Price-amount"}).text
            job_no += 1
            npo_jobs[job_no] = [categoryPageName, product_code, product_image, product_name, product_desc,
                                product_price]
        print("Crossing this line shows presence of Dropdonw")
        while dpflag > 0:
            select_fr.select_by_index(dpflag)
            htmlPage1 = driver.page_source
            soupPage1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage, "html.parser")
            container1 = soupPage1.findAll("div", {"id": "product-row"})
            time.sleep(5)
            product_image = container1[0].find("img", {"class": "wp-post-image"})['src']
            product_name = container1[0].find("h1", {"class": "entry-title"}).text
            product_code = ""
            try:
                product_code = container1[0].find("div", {"class": "suma-woo-product-sku"}) #.text
            except:
                pass  # doing nothing on exception
            product_desc = ""
            try:
                product_desc = container1[0].find("div", {"class": "lead"}).text
            except:
                try:
                    product_desc = container1[0].find("div", {"class": "lead"}).text
                except:
                    pass  # doing nothing on exception
            product_price = container1[0].find("span", {"class": "woocommerce-Price-amount"}).text
            job_no += 1
            npo_jobs[job_no] = [categoryPageName, product_code, product_image, product_name, product_desc, product_price]
            dpflag -= 1

    npo_jobs_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(npo_jobs, orient='index',
                                         columns=["Category Name", "Product Code", "Product Image", "Product Name",
                                                  "Product Description", "Product Price"])
    npo_jobs_df.to_csv('./csv/newarchery_Records.csv')
```

In the code section starting with

```
while dpflag > 0:
```

I am changing the index of the dropdown which adds the product code to the webpage. I tried to get the page_source again to load that additional element (product code) and then **scrape** the product code but it still shows me blank.

You can try any webite as an example. I tried with [www.newarchery.com](http://www.newarchery.com)

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a bug in the code

```
    select_fr.select_by_index(dpflag)
    htmlPage1 = driver.page_source
    soupPage1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage, "html.parser")
    container1 = soupPage1.findAll("div", {"id": "product-row"})
    time.sleep(5)
```

First of all, I need the timer to place before htmlPage1 to load the content. The other error is in line 3 above where I am parsing the older page htmlPage where it should be htmlPage1.

so changing above to

```
    select_fr.select_by_index(dpflag)
    time.sleep(5)
    htmlPage1 = driver.page_source
    soupPage1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage1, "html.parser")
    container1 = soupPage1.findAll("div", {"id": "product-row"})
```

I am able to solve this.

Thanks